# Como saber las etapas que ha pasado un usuario en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo 3 tablas en `mysql`:
 tabla usuario:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
`usuario` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Tengo una tabla donde estan almacenadas las etapas como catalogo

```
  CREATE TABLE `timeline_mapa` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
`descripcion` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Y tengo la tabla de las etapas que va pasando un usuario:

```
CREATE TABLE `timeline_usuario` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_timeline` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Lo que deseo es traer todas las etapas de la tabla `timeline_mapa` y a la par una columna para saber si ese usuario ya paso la etapa o aun le falta

He probado la siguiente consulta que me arroja la tabla como quisiera que saliera, pero me falta poner el `WHERE u.usuario = '1234'`:

```
SELECT m.nombre,t.id
FROM timeline_mapa as m
left join timeline_usuario t on t.id_timeline = m.id
left join user u on u.id= t.id_user
```

Al poner esa condicion solo me trae la etapa que le usuario ha pasado,pero busco la siguiente salida:

```
  |'1. Primera Visita'  | '1' |
  |'1.1 Apoyo emocional'| NULL|
  |'2 PDT '             | NULL|
  |'3 Fecha'            | NULL|
```

Comment: Hola Igmer, ¿nos puedes pasar el dataset (los INSERT con los datos) para comprobar si nos sale el mismo resultado que a ti? Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Al poner el `WHERE u.usuario = '1234'` le estás diciendo que te genere todas las líneas que combinen la primera tabla con las otras dos, y que quieres que te de aquellas líneas que tienen user 1234, por lo que descartas aquellas que con el left join quedarían con user vacío. La formas más fácil de verlo es cambiando `SELECT m.nombre,t.id` por `SELECT *`.

Realmente, si entiendo bien, lo que quieres es que saque todas las etapas y que, para un user, te diga si las ha pasado o no, así que esto

```
SELECT m.nombre, t.id
FROM timeline_mapa AS m
LEFT JOIN timeline_usuario t ON t.id_timeline = m.id
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id= t.id_user AND u.usuario = '1234'
```

debería de funcionarte, ya que estás acotando la tabla antes del cruce, no después.